# Nginx server block is not being picked

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have created a new subdomain and updated the following vhost configuration file but nginx still picking the default one (the first server block)

Knowing that both blocks listen to same IP:PORT !! Any ideas why the second block is not picked when accessing the subdomain ?

```
server {
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
        charset off;
        disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
        index index.php index.html;
        root $root_path;
        set $root_path /var/www/udomain/data/www/domain.net;
        access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/domain.com.access.log ;
        error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/domain.com.error.log notice;
        include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
        location / {
            location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
            }
            location / {
                try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
            }
            location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
                try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
            }
        }
        location @fallback {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                access_log off ;
        }
        ssi on;
        listen IP-Address:80;
}
server {
    server_name subdomain.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:SOMEPORT/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    listen IP-Address:80;
    ssi on;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you connect to the same ip for subdomain? Have you reloaded nginx?

Comment: Same IP & execute after each change service nginx restart

Comment: Have you checked that `subdomain.domain.com` resolves to the same IP?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write your listen directives as follows:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.com;

    location {
        ...
    }
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  subdomain.domain.com;

    location {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, here's a great explanation on how Nginx selects which server block to use: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

If you're accessing via a browser, I suggest taking a look at the `Host` header, and based on the above tutorial you can build an appropriate server block.

Comment: I have subdomain not different domains!

Comment: Sorry, answer edited. Point is, don't write the IP address, just the port.

Comment: Still not working. I tried to change to port 81 and still not working. So i have tested the port with # netstat -anp | grep 81
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:81              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7279/nginx: master

Comment: How about changing `server_name domain.com www.domain.com;` in the top server block to `server_name .domain.com;`? This is how I did it on my site.

Comment: The problem is with the second block. Its not being picked. Now the weird part is if i change the port to 81 then i get response time-out when i request the subdomain!!

Comment: Yes, I am aware that the problematic block is the second one. But Nginx processes them from top to bottom, so maybe your `Host` header matches the top block and thus get thrown there.

About the port change, your firewall or ISP may be blocking port 81, so better just use 80.