# whats is nginx location blacklist

Tags: nginx

What does **location @blacklist** means ?

```
location @blacklist {
proxy_redirect off ;
proxy_pass https://ip-address:1500;
rewrite (.*) /mancgi/ddos break;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@name in location is just an identifier:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

> The “@” prefix defines a named location. Such a location is not used
>   for a regular request processing, but instead used for request
>   redirection. They cannot be nested, and cannot contain nested
>   locations.

Comment: So what does the location block means ?

Comment: Well, why did you write it like that? Or where did you copy it from? It means whatever the person who wrote the code wants it to mean.

Comment: Its part of my ngninx configuration files (blacklist-ngninx.conf). As you can see this location is a reverse proxy to port 1500. The posted location is part of server block that is listening to port 80.

Comment: So am trying to solve another problem posted here: http://serverfault.com/questions/768785/nginx-server-block-is-not-being-picked